# Python 2.7 Extract data from URL

Tags: python-2.7, url, extract

I'm new to Python and try to extract data from an URL and fail miserably.
I've searched but I only find working solutions for Python 3.x

I'm trying to extract data from an browser redirection for example:

http://test.com?action=go&transaction=1244556&result=ok

I want to pipe it into a dictionary.

I've tried urllib and co but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: If you put the code you've tried, people may be able to help correct it.

Comment: The problem is I don't have much code beside the code which results in the URL. I've tried urllib but I don't find a parameter like urlparse which exists in Python 3.x which provides the parameters. I can do a more manual approach by splitting the URL at the & and = and put them into a dictionary, but, I might be wrong, but I think there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may mention in your VIEW regarding the GET / POST methods () through with query strings can be accessed. Then you can manipulate the query string values in your scripts.

Alternatively more efficient options could also to utilise REQUESTS - https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/ or HTTPLIB2 - https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2.

Comment: I'm not sure about your first sentence. Can you describe in more details.

Currently I get the URL with selenium:

currenturl = browser.current_url